# Minimum Cost Network Optimization Software

Tags: performance, computer-science

I'm trying to solve a Minimum Cost Network Flow problem (for assigning students to their preferred classes). I've tried [GIDEN](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~giden/) but the software isn't great. Does anyone know of other options?

Answer (score 1):

check out these:

**[Solvers for the Minimum Cost Network Flow Problem](http://ftp.zib.de/pub/Packages/mathprog/mincost/index.html)**

*from the Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum für Informationstechnik Berlin*

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  I'm not referring to computer networks.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cost_flow_problem

Comment: my bad, sorry for the misunderstanding :)